# Amazon Personalize dataset import job creation failed

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-personalize

My schema look is like:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Interactions",
    "namespace": "com.amazonaws.personalize.schema",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "USER_ID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "ITEM_ID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "TIMESTAMP",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "EVENT_TYPE",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "EVENT_VALUE",
            "type": "float"
        },
        {
            "name": "SESSION_ID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "SERVICE_TYPE",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "SERVICE_LOCATION",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "SERVICE_PRICE",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "SERVICE_TIME",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "USER_LOCATION",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

I uploaded my .CSV file in S3 bucket user-flights-bucket. When I tried to uploaded it to personalize it failed with the reason:

> Path does not exist: s3://user-flights-bucket/null;

Answer (score 0):

S3://user-flights-bucket/"*give ur file name*.csv"

It will work..give this in the data location